# Why I don't see the second plot?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello I writed this code using javascript and Chart.js :

```
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), 

{type:'line', 
    data: {
        labels: [18.123,46.8603108462,75.5976216923,104.334932538],
        datasets: [{
            data: [418872.777267,262233.131655,180687.131758,133676.324505],
            label: "Model",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false     
        }]      
    }
    },
{
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {

    datasets: [{
label : 'Data',
fill:false,
showLine: false,
backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
data : [{x: 17.0, y: 454995.091169},
{x: 18.0, y: 457656.874749},
{x: 19.0, y: 444574.49162},
{x: 20.0, y: 432511.514968},
{x: 21.0, y: 421184.776328}],
}]
},
options: {
title:{
display: true,
text:"Test"},
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic',
                position: 'bottom'
            }],
yAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic'
            }]
        }
    }
}
 );
</script>
```

And the problem is I don't see the scatter plot, I see only the first plot. Actually I would like to plot these two plot on the same graph in logarithmic scale.

Thank you very much !

Comment: [Here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html) is API describing what you want. You must define another chart inside `datasets`.

Comment: But in my case I have not the same abscissa :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one dataset with type "scatter" in the line datasets. You can checkout their mixed chart documentation here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html.

You can checkout my running example here https://jsfiddle.net/sherlcode13/m3mfz6jh/5/

```
    var ctx = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [18.123,46.8603108462,75.5976216923,104.334932538],
        datasets: [{
            data: [418872.777267,262233.131655,180687.131758,133676.324505],
            label: "Model",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false     
        }, {
            label : 'Data',
            fill:false,
            showLine: false,
            data : [{x: 17.0, y: 454995.091169},
            {x: 18.0, y: 457656.874749},
            {x: 19.0, y: 444574.49162},
            {x: 20.0, y: 432511.514968},
            {x: 21.0, y: 421184.776328}],
                type: 'scatter'
        }
            ]        
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text:"Test"
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic',
                position: 'bottom'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                type: 'logarithmic'
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I only get the points not the line :/

Comment: Hi @PeterHarris Have you checked mine jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/m3mfz6jh/ ?

Comment: Yes but I just see a white screen when I clik on run :/

Comment: Hi @PeterHarris Sorry I don't know what went wrong in that link. Please check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sherlcode13/m3mfz6jh/5/

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I wanted ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mixed chart, it is possible to create mixed charts that are a combination of two or more different chart types

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html

Comment: Yes I saw this but in my case the abscissa are different whereas in the case you mentionned you have the same abscissa by the name of labels